# How to change the Rails server from single threaded to MultiThreaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Project, one controller action uploads the file. i just want to show the progress of fileupload. I wrote one Javascript Polling mechanism, which will get the status of file upload for every 5 seconds. but my rails server starts handling my poll requests after the file upload action ends. I think that my rails server is single threaded. I tried Puma and Thin gems too. but nothing seems to be working for me. Please help me to get rid from this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) which supports multiple file uploads with progress bar.

Some good references include:

1. http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
2. http://5minutenpause.com/blog/2013/09/04/multiple-file-upload-with-jquery-rails-4-and-paperclip/ (Using paperclip)
3. http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload?view=comments (if you have subscribed)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You could start using jruby. It runs inside the JVM and is by design multithreaded. You can quite easily use multiple threads in your code then.

@rajesh-c-o As the author of the second link: Thanks for mentioning it.